# how to navigate and pass the data to other screen? Also need to clear that screen from back stack

Tags: flutter

I want to navigate from first screen to second. I want to send some data along with it.I also need to clear the first screen from back stack, so that when i press back button on second screen it should not come to first screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
  SecondPage(stuffToSend: "yourStuff")));

class SecondPage{
 SecondPage({this.stuffToSend});
 var stuffToSend;
 //the rest of your code
}
```